# H2 In-Memory DB, How can I see tables structure?

Tags: database, eclipse, maven, jboss, h2

**Hi,**

I’m using maven “Jboss-Spring-mvc-archetype” which comes with H2  In-memory database. the data source definition:

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/SpringMvcJpaJBossDSBasic"
                pool-name="SpringMvcJpaJBoss" enabled="true"
                use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:SpringMvcJpaJBoss-quickstart;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
```

In my application I can see the data and able to do all CRUD operations

**The problem:**

How can I see the tables structure? I’ve been trying using eclipse data source explorer but it keeps displaying two schemas  (information_schema and public)  without my tables!

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you that the contents of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` shows none of your tables or schemas? What results do you get for `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`? The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for H2 is [documented here](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#information_schema).

Comment: Yes I can't see it, I've edited the post and added some screens, please have  a look.